# How to manage state of input values with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm building a React component that is effectively a carousel.

Sometimes, this carousel (which I've called Slides) will have form data in that needs validating and collecting at the end.

I pass down a the form question and accompanying input in Page.slideData function. I pass down a small schema for the form also, telling Slides how each separate slide should be validated.

My issue is getting a reference to the value of each input. In Slides.collectData func I test against a "testing" string. But I cannot figure out how to get the value of the current input in place of the "testing" string. I will also need all the form data at the end, and will pass it back to the parent once the end it reached.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.slideData = this.slideData.bind(this);
    this.formSchema = this.formSchema.bind(this);
  }
  slideData() {
    return [
        label: `When is this thing?`,
        input: <input type="text" />,
      }, {
        label: 'Will this be private?',
        input: <input type="checkbox" />,
      },
    ];
  }
  formSchema() {
    return [
      { key: 'date', validate: String },
      { key: 'isPrivate', validate: Boolean },
    ];
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <main className="Page">
        <Slides
          data={this.slideData()}
          formSchema={this.formSchema()}
        />
      </main>
    );
  }
}


class Slides extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      position: 1,
      qty: this.props.data.length,
      error: null,
    }
    this.cycle = this.cycle.bind(this);
  }
  moveSlides(newPosition) {
    const { qty } = this.state;
    if (newPosition < 1 || newPosition > qty) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      position: newPosition,
      error: null,
    });
  }
  cycle(num) {
    const { position } = this.state;
    const newPosition = position + num;
    if (this.props.formSchema) {
      this.collectData(position, newPosition);
    } else {
      this.moveSlides(newPosition);
    }
  }
  collectData(position, newPosition) {
    const { formSchema } = this.props;
    const currentSlideSchema = formSchema[position - 1];

    const { collectedData } = this.state;
    let newCollectedData = Object.assign({}, collectedData);
    newCollectedData[currentSlideSchema.key] = 'testing';

    if (
      Match.test(
        newCollectedData[currentSlideSchema.key],
        currentSlideSchema.validate
      ) || position > newPosition) {
      this.setState({ collectedData: newCollectedData });
      this.moveSlides(newPosition);
    } else {
      this.setState({ error: "Invalid entry" });
    }
  }
  renderSlides() {
    const { position } = this.state;
    const { data } = this.props;

    return data.map((slide, idx) => {
      const index = idx + 1;
      let alignment;
      if (index === position) {
        alignment = 'active';
      } else if (index > position) {
        alignment = 'right';
      } else {
        alignment = 'left';
      }
      return (
        <Slide
          label={slide.label}
          input={slide.input}
          key={`Slide_${idx}`}
          alignment={alignment}
        />
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { position, error } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="Slides">
        <div className="Slides_ContentWrapper">
          {this.renderSlides()}
        </div>
        { error &&
          <span className="Slides_Error">{error}</span>
        }
        <div className="Slides_Buttons">
          <button>onClick={() => this.cycle(-1)}>Go back</button>
          <button>onClick={() => this.cycle(1)}>Go Forward</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Slide extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { label, input, alignment } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={`Slide Slide--${alignment}`}>
        <span className="Slide_Label">{ label }</span>
        { input }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass react elements down from your page, instead just have the `Slide` render an input and pass the relevant props in, e.g. the `type`.

You then use `onChange` event handler on the input which will pass the users input through as the first parameter.

To get the value of this back up to the parents (Page or Slides, not sure which you want? but same principle anyway) just pass the callback function down from the parent instead of defining the callback on the child. e.g.

```
   <Slide
      label={slide.label}
      input={slide.input}
      key={`Slide_${idx}`}
      alignment={alignment}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />
```

Comment: It's a good idea, and I thought of doing it this way, but I will need to pass down other components as props, like <Calendar /> etc. So I do need to pass down unfortunately.

Comment: @mildrenben No you don't. You can just pass the components down as props like you would any other prop